# github new local branch event for Jira webhook

Tags: github, jira

I am noticing that when i create a new local branch, it doesn't get picked up in Github, and therefore the Jira webhook also doesn't create a transition trigger:

```
git branch -b new-local-branch
```

The Jira trigger is supposed to recognize "Branch created" event from Github webhook, but that doesn't exist until I push, which also then shows the new branch for the first time in the `<>Code` tab.

So, is this performing as expected, or is there another way to create a branch which gets pickedup without a push?

Answer (score 1):

> So, is this performing as expected

Yes: a webhook reacts to an event (here a push event).
As long as your branch remains local, said webhook has no reason to be activated.

But once created, you could push your branch immediately (before making any new commit in it): that would allow the webhook and Jira to pick up on it.

> Is there another way to create a branch which gets picked-up without a push?

If you are creating your local branch from a commit which is already pushed, you could consider the reverse approach: [creating your branch directly from GitHub web GUI](https://github.com/blog/1377-create-and-delete-branches). But that might not trigger the webhook though.